# Нужна ли запятая при обособлении с помощью тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

*Один из них - тот, кто носил меч(,) - принес с собой мешок с порошком.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Нужна**, потому что она закрывает оборот *"...кто носил меч..."*.

Пример из справочника Лопатина:

> Сводки погоды — замирало всё в доме, когда начинали их передавать, —
> казались однообразными и тупыми, потому что в них не было явлений и
> бурно нарастающих признаков начинающейся весны (Сол.)